# Is mass of a particle changed when it is charged?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a particle of mass $M$ is given an electric charge $Q$, will its mass change?

Comment: How would you go about charging a particle?

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean with "particle"? How would you add a charge?

If you add an electron to an atom you will increase the mass by the electron mass (of course) minus a tiny contribution coming from $m=E/c^2$ where E is the work done taking the electron from where it was to its actual position in the Coulomb potential.

Answer (score 3):

since charge in everyday life can only be given by adding or removing electrons,therefore mass will definitely change.